# How to make a mixed-type struct from function args?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I need to create an array of structs for a struct that looks like this:

```
struct myStruct {
   address _address;
   uint _num;
}
```

And I need to create the array from function args.

I'm doing this by using 2 params (`address[]` & `uint[]`) that represent the 2 struct members, and for looping through them to create the array of structs. Is there a simpler way?
Potentially using

```
ethers.utils.AbiCoder.prototype.encode(
  ['address', 'uint'],
  [<address>, <number>]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to encode it.

you can build the input like this:

```
   let  myStruct = {
    _address: accounts[2].address,
    _num: web3.utils.toWei("1")
  }
```

Then just call your function with the struct as the input

Comment: Realized this eventually, thanks

Comment: It will actually be an array of structs that will be saved to storage. Is there a way, other than for looping, to save a struct[] memory arg to struct[] storage?

Comment: haven't done that personally, so wouldn't know, but I doubt it.  I've had troubles even doing arrays in a struct